# SQL Server 2008 database seems unavailable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've had this current issue before, and the steps that I've used to resolve it in the past aren't working. I'm working with a database in SSMS, as well as through C#/.NET. When I encounter a bug on the C# side after connecting to the database, the db becomes inaccessible until I close visual studio, and then in prior situations, taking the db offline then on again. I'm looking for more ideas/ help, since after doing those things, a simple query:

```
SELECT TradeDate, Symbol, Clse
FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol
```

gives me

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'tblDailyPricingAndVol'.
```

(whereas it is valid, and I type it right after expanding it in object explorer in ssms).

**Update**:
Running that query with db/ schema prefix as such:

```
SELECT Market.dbo.TradeDate
FROM Market.dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol
```

Returns the error:

> Msg 945, Level 14, State 2, Line 1
>   Database 'Market' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.

Running this:

```
select name, state_desc, user_access_desc, is_read_only  from sys.databases
```

tells me that my db is online. I closed visual studio and restarted my machine last night, then took the db offline then on, and I don't see anything like "recovery pending" etc. today still. I'd like to get back up and running, and if anyone can shed some light on this process of connecting/ disconnecting SQL Server 2008 with Visual Studio 2010, it'd be much appreciated..

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right database? Just because you've expanded something in Object Explorer doesn't automatically update the database scope in your query window. Also to be sure you should always use the schema prefix, e.g. `FROM dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol`...

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I'll update my post to reflect results using schema prefix..

Comment: Ok, and did you look at the error log for anything involving the Market database?

Comment: There are several: Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38; Error 5170, Severity: 16, State: 1; and "A file activation error occured. The physical file name 'c:\myFilepath' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors."

Comment: Sounds like you haven't correctly attached the database.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not what variables could have changed (location path etc) but I have a lot to learn... any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a valid copy of the MDF file, or a backup somewhere? I'm sure you didn't mean to create or attach a database where the MDF file was `c:\myFilepath`...

Comment: Yup, I see it in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA (Market.mdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. Make a copy of your Market.mdf file and store it somewhere safe.

B. Run the following commands in a query window:

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE Market SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; -- may fail
GO
DROP DATABASE Market; -- may fail depending on whether this db really exists
GO
CREATE DATABASE Market ON ( FILENAME = 
  'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Market.mdf'
) FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

If this fails due to some error with the log file (.ldf), then try moving the market.ldf file elsewhere, and running:

```
CREATE DATABASE Market ON ( FILENAME = 
  'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Market.mdf'
) FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

To prevent similar problems in the future:

Don't detach your database. 

Don't connect to your MDF file using the `AttachDbFileName` and `User Instance` settings.

Don't set your database to `OFFLINE`. 

Don't set your database to Auto-Close.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not out of the woods yet though.. I copied the db. Ran your script, and after it dropped, I got an error stating the file couldn't be found. I copied the .mdf file back in to the \DATA folder and reran the create db statement. It was successful. I wasn't prompted for anything regarding the log file, but I see a message that a new one was created. Now, I reenter the same select query from my original post, and I get the same error: "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'tblDailyPricingAndVol'."

Comment: Ok, so is it at all possible that this table doesn't actually exist? E.g. Your MDF file is a copy from before this table was created, or you're spelling it wrong? Are you sure you have permissions to access it? What happens when you right-click it in Object Explorer and choose SELECT TOP 1000?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 returns records... I even rename/copy/pasted the table name into my query in case it was that stupid. Same error. Here's the query: SELECT MAX(Market.dbo.TradeDate)
FROM Market.dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol. Unlike before we recreated the db, at least the table appeared in intellisense. But on execution, the error..

Comment: Without actually watching you do this, I can't tell what you're doing wrong, sorry. If the table exists for one operation, it should exist for the other, you're obviously either connecting to the wrong server or doing something else I can't fathom...

Comment: I just took the db/ schema identifiers off, now it works. Whew. Thanks for your solution and patience.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly why it should work without the db/schema identifiers, unless you're in a different db or your object is under a different schema, but ok...

Comment: I'm not sure either. That's the only schema though.. if you're still following this, is there a known way to clean up after throwing an error from an app connected to the db? Seems rather precarious to have happen every time. I can't find much that speaks to this on msdn.